# Primefaces p:calendar wont update backingbean when time changes

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, calendar

**Prerequisites:**
- JSF 2.1
- Primefaces 5.2
- Glassfish 3.1

**Story**
I want the user to input a timerange (from day x hh:mm until day z hh:mm). For this i am useing two calendars, looking like this:

```
<p:calendar value="#{myBean.startDate}" navigator="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm">            
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" process="@this"></p:ajax>
</p:calendar>
```

**Problem**
If i change the date of the calendar the value "startDate" in my backingbean is updated. But if i change the time with the two sliders of the calendar, it won't update until i again select a date. When i close the calendar the new time is shown in the interface. But when i call my save action and reference to the values of the backingbean, all changes done to the time since the last date-change are ignored since they haven't been changed in the backing bean

**Question**
Is there an ajax-event which is fired if the time of a calendar is being changed? Currently im useing the "dateSelect" event as you can see. Sadly i couldn't find anything about a "timeSelect" event or something similar. The change event / onChangeListeners of the calendar won't do the job either.

Comment: Tried a newer version of PF?

Comment: @Kukeltje This version is requested. I can't change it.

Comment: TRY.... if it works you know it is a bug in the version you use and you can investigate the latest source for a workaround. If it does not work in a newer version, you also know that...